# Azure Live Metrics shows 'Empty' role server. What purpose of this server?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have Azure Web App service, and on the live metrics tool I have 2 servers: "PF2Z..." and "RD0003FF...." but only one application is running.
"RD0003FF...." server is my application because if I stop the app this server disappears, but "PF2Z..." is still present, and even more this server takes more than 20gb of RAM according to data on live metrics. Web App reboot does not help.

**Question** What kind of server ("PF2Z...") is it and is it needed? If not, how can I stop it?
[image: Example]

I have tried to reboot the application, but it does not help.

search *  | project cloud_RoleName, cloud_RoleInstance | distinct * -
[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Klh.png)

Comment: So probably there is some other instance running somewhere you do not know about. Try query the cloud_RoleName and cloud_RoleInstance properties to try and get more details

Comment: Where can I query this?

Comment: Using the [logs](https://azure.github.io/Industrial-IoT/tutorials/tut-applicationinsights.html) and a query like `search * 
| project cloud_RoleName, cloud_RoleInstance | distinct *`.

Comment: Tried your query, and received this information, added a screenshot to question